# Extract Max Values from Cut Section in Abaqus/CAE

Tags: abaqus, abaqus-odb

I want to extract the max values of a field output of a cut section of my model for every section using a python script. The issue is that the max values shown on Contour Plot Options displays the max values for the whole 3d model and not the cut section (2d on z axis) on the viewport. This can be confirmed by the legend shown on the viewport for that cut section.

[image: Contour Plot Options Max Value Differs from 2d Cut section of 3d Model]
[image: Contour Plot Options Max Value and Legend Max Value in Red are same]

I require the max value that is shown in legend for that specific cut section for all the increments. If it possible to extract of 1 frame using python script, I can loop it for all the increments.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `getPrimVarMinMaxLoc()` method available for `viewport` object.

> This method returns a dictionary containing the minimum, maximum and their location for the current primary variable. A contour plot should be displayed in the current viewport or else the method will return None.

```
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].getPrimVarMinMaxLoc()

# {'maxPartInstanceName': 'COLUMN-1', 'maxPosition': 'Node: 37093', 'maxElementLabel': 31753,
#  'maxValue': 251.432723999023, 'minValue': 1.9861044883728,
#  'minPartInstanceName': 'COLUMN-1', 'minElementLabel': 28782,
#  'minPosition': 'Node: 35672'}
```